# how to implement a "Read More" button with Get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on an image gallary inside a web templete. where each image is constrcuted as follow:-

```
<li>
<figure><a href="~/img/big.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="~/img/small.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Villa</em><img src="~/img/search.png" alt=""></span></a></figure>
</li>
```

now as shown inside the markup, when the user visit the page the small.jpg will be rendered , then if he click on the small.jpg , another image named big.jpg will be shown inside a jquery slider, here is a sample on a real website http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47767/index-2.html

now what i want to do is to replace the search.png with a button or a link (although adding a link will not work because the markup is already inside a link !!) with "Read More" label, so if the user clicks on the ReadMore either on the slider or inside the normal web page to redirect him to another page ?

can anyone adivce on this please ?

second question. i am trying this more complex scenario, is to keep the current search.png inside the web page , but to replace it with "ReadMore" on the slider ?

**EDIT**
i want to avoid adding additional span inside my markup since there is a script which are going to read the span and display them inside the jquery slider. so i replaced the span with a text as follow:

```
  <li>
    <figure><a href="~/img/big.jpg" class="thumb"><img src="~/img/small.jpg" alt=""><span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Villa</em><text class="read-more" data-goto="/Home/">Read More</text></span></a></figure>
    </li>
```

and here is the script:-

```
 <script>

    $(function () {
        $('.read-more').on("click", function (e) {

            window.location = $(this).attr('data-goto');
            e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents the anchor click from triggering.
        });
    })
    </script>
```

but currently inside the slider i will get the following text,

[image]

but when i click on it i will not be redirected to the home page , instead the jquery slider will be dismissed. and if i am inside the web page (not inside the jquery slider) and i lick on ReadMore i will just get the picture on my browser...

BTW here is the callback function inside the touch.jquery.js script which i wrote to add the span inside the slider:-

```
function loadImage(src, callback){
            var img = $('<img>').on('load', function(){
                callback.call(img);
            });

            img.attr('src', src);
            var allcaptions = $("figure span");

            // setTimeout is a hack here, since the ".placeholders" don't exist yet
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(".placeholder").each(function (i) {

                    // in each .placeholder, copy its caption's mark-up into it (remove the img first)
                    var caption = allcaptions.eq(i).clone();
                    caption.find("img").remove();
                    $(this).append("<div class='caption'>" + caption.html() + "</div>");
                });
            }, 500
    );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a span tag with the data attribute containing your url in place of the search image.

```
<li>
    <figure>
        <a href="~/img/big.jpg" class="thumb">
            <img src="~/img/small.jpg" alt=""/>
            <span><strong>Project name:</strong><em>Villa</em>
                <span class="read-more" data-goto='/read/more/url'>Read More</span>
            </span>
       </a>
    </figure>
</li>
```

then the javascript would be:

```
$(function(){
    $('.read-more').click(function(e){
        window.location = $(this).attr('data-goto');
        e.stopPropagation(); // this prevents the anchor click from triggering.
    });
})
```

Comment: thanks for the help,, but this will not work as expected,, can u please check my edit ?